# Why does chabad say "Yisbareich" instead of "yisbarach"?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, prayer-book, chabad, kaddish, nuschaot

Why according to the Nusach Ari (siddur "Tehilat Hashem") does it say "yisba**reich**" instead of "yisba**rach**" in Kaddish?

Comment: [This](http://www.haoros.com/Archive/?kovetz=803&Cat=11&haoro=0) should explain it.

Comment: comes down to being a machloikes rishoinim and is discussed in kitzur sa 15 laws of kaddish, barechu, requirements of a minyan, & laws for the tzibur

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because the verb התברך is binyan *Hitpa’el*, gizrah: ע׳ גרונית א, ר.

In 2nd person, masculine, future tense, the correct conjugation is *Yitbareich*.

If you have a question, see Sefer Luchot Po’alim by Asher Tarmone and Ezri Uval, pg. 129, table 136.